# Prove that $S$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

This is with respect to Chapter 9 of [A First Course in Algebraic Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521298644).

Let $X$ be the set of real numbers with the topology
$\{\emptyset\} \cup \{\mathbb{R}\} \cup \bigl\{(-\infty,x)\mid\ x \in \mathbb{R}\bigr\}.$

The book attempts to show that any subset of $X$ is connected.

The proof goes like this:

Let $S$ be any subset of $X$. Suppose that $F$ is a non-empty subset of $S$ which is both open and closed in $S$. Thus we may write $F$ as $U \cap S=C \cap S$ where $U$ is open in $X$ and $C$ is closed in $X$.

i.e

$$U=(-\infty,b)$$ for some $b$ and

$$C=[a,\infty)$$

for some $a$. Since $F=U \cap S = C \cap S$ then it follows that if $x \in S$ then $x<b$ and $x \ge a$ (Otherwise $U \cap S \not=C \cap S$)

Thus $S \subseteq [a,b)$ $\color{red}{\text{and hence }F=S}$ which means that $S$ is connected.

I don't get why $F=S$, can anyone kindly explain it to me?

Comment: We should perhaps describe $S$ as a *proper* subset of $X$, for the sake of the argument being advanced.

Comment: Hmm, I concur, but I've just typed it out as the book states..

Comment: I think we need to explain why $a \leq b$ but it is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know $S\subseteq [a,b)\subset U$, put $F=U\cap S = (-\infty,b)\cap S = S$.

Comment: Yes, then why is $S=[a,b)$? The question only states $S \subseteq [a,b)$.

Comment: Yes, I misstated it.  Let me edit...

Comment: Great! So the key step was $[a,b) \subset U$! Thank you!

Comment: The argument is a little lacking, related to the omission of "proper subsets".  If $U$ were all of $X$, then of course we'd have $F = U\cap S = S$, immediately.  So a trivial (but special) case is being omitted.

Answer (score 0):

For $S\subseteq [a,b)$, notice that $U\cap S=C \cap S$. We obtain $$S-U\cap S=S-C\cap S.$$ That should be $\emptyset$ since $$x\in (S-U\cap S )\Rightarrow x \geqslant b,$$ but $$x\in(S-C\cap S)\Rightarrow x<a.$$ Then $S\subseteq [a,b)$ follows immediately.

Comment: I missed something.  Why is it obvious that $S \supseteq [a,b)$?  It has to rely on something omitted in the argument, since initially $S$ can be any subset at all of $X$.

Comment: @hardmath My apologize, I missed the S part of the equation $F=(U\cap S)\cap (C\cap S)\subseteq S$...