# Topological space in which there are no close and compacts subsets (except for the empty set)

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Any example of those topological spaces? I cant think of no one :S

I think it must be infinite and it must not be T2, but no idea how to find one.

Comment: The empty set is always closed and compact.

Comment: @MartianInvader sorry, except for the empty set

Comment: @DavidMitra but a finite collection of points of that space will be  closed and compact, wont it?

Comment: Sorry, bad moment for me ...

Comment: A finite set of points will always be compact, but not necessarily closed.

Comment: @hardmath But there are some set of points which are closed, right?. I need a subspace in which there are no closed and compact subsets

Comment: Right, you need a lack of Hausdorff separation properties so severe that no finite set is closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb R$ with the topology whse open sets are:

- $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$;
- the open halflines $(a,\infty)$ for $a\in\Bbb R$.

Then every closed set $(-\infty,a]$ admits a covering in open sets which admits no finite subcovering, namely
$$
(-\infty,a]\subset\cup_{n=1}^\infty(a-n,\infty)
$$

Comment: Essentially this same topology was the subject of [a different Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/639315/3111) early today, about the connectedness of any nonempty subset.

Comment: @hardmath: I missed that